# 4HDDs in RAID 10 One specific disk becomes degraded during every reboot. Is the disk bad? Smartmoontools information included

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid, smart, intel-rst

So this all began about 6 months ago when I swapped in a new motherboard. The RAID had previously been my main drive that I booted into. I upgraded cpus which meant a mobo upgrade, and along with that I swapped to an SSD as my main drive. I didn't do anything fancy to bring the new RAID along, I dropped the drives in and installed the RAID drivers then rebooted to switch RAID on in BIOS. Everything looked intact except this one drive which showed up degraded during that first boot.

Once I loaded into Windows the Intel RST software automatically began a repair which took 2ish hours to complete. After which all looked fine, so I powered down. I went ahead and reopened the case, rechecking all the cables/connections/drive seating etc. Everything was fine on that end.

Then it showed as degraded again during the following boot, and it repaired itself again without a hitch. So I switched which ports the drives were on, but the same issue persisted with the same drive degrading. I moved any really important files I wanted off the RAID and I've been using it as storage since then. Haven't noticed any problems between reboots when I store or retrieve files on the RAID. Regardless during those rare times when I reboot the drive reports as degraded again like clockwork.

During repairs the drive is marked with a warning but no other pertinent information. After repair [Intel's RST tool looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pSHg.png) Individual disks each report Status: Normal.

After some time of this, I'm considering breaking down the RAID but before I do I'd like to know what's really up with this drive since it seemed highly coincidental that everything was working zero problems until the moment I switched mobos. Old drive but hey if it works I'd like to keep it for emergency or temporary storage.

Anyways I couldn't find much information with the Intel RST alone, and logs were nowhere to be found so I came upon smartmontools and tried that using the command line

```
smartctl -a /dev/csmi0,3
```

0,3 being the troubled drive which yields the following:

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-w64-mingw32-win7-sp1] (sf-6.5-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Maxtor DiamondMax 10 (ATA/133 and SATA/150)
Device Model:     Maxtor 6B300S0
Serial Number:    B60NDB2H
Firmware Version: BANC1B70
User Capacity:    300,090,728,448 bytes [300 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA/ATAPI-7 T13/1532D revision 0
Local Time is:    Mon Jan 16 23:28:51 2017 PST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed

                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                ( 2283) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off supp
ort.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 118) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_
FAILED RAW_VALUE
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   183   149   063    Pre-fail  Always       -
       28226
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   250   250   000    Old_age   Always       -
       6749
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   140   140   063    Pre-fail  Always       -
       1149
  6 Read_Channel_Margin     0x0001   253   253   100    Pre-fail  Offline      -
       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000a   253   247   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0027   250   231   187    Pre-fail  Always       -
       56890
  9 Power_On_Minutes        0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -
       851h+19m
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x002b   253   209   157    Pre-fail  Always       -
       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x002b   253   252   223    Pre-fail  Always       -
       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   251   251   000    Old_age   Always       -
       1014
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0032   044   253   000    Old_age   Always       -
       48
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x000a   253   212   000    Old_age   Always       -
       22159
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0008   253   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -
       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0008   253   249   000    Old_age   Offline      -
       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   253   252   000    Old_age   Offline      -
       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0008   199   199   000    Old_age   Offline      -
       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x000a   253   252   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
201 Soft_Read_Error_Rate    0x000a   253   252   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
202 Data_Address_Mark_Errs  0x000a   253   233   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
203 Run_Out_Cancel          0x000b   253   252   180    Pre-fail  Always       -
       1
204 Soft_ECC_Correction     0x000a   253   252   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
205 Thermal_Asperity_Rate   0x000a   253   252   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
207 Spin_High_Current       0x002a   253   209   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
208 Spin_Buzz               0x002a   253   252   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
209 Offline_Seek_Performnce 0x0024   240   240   000    Old_age   Offline      -
       161
210 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   253   252   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
211 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   253   252   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0
212 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -
       0

Read SMART Log Directory failed: CSMI(25) failed with ReturnCode=1

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 368 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 368 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 11897 hours (495 days + 17 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown
state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  78 00 01 10 00 00 40

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  00 00 01 10 00 00 40 00      02:43:33.823  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 80 40 00 19 d0 40 00      02:43:32.365  NOP [Reserved subcommand] [OBS-ACS-
2]
  00 80 38 80 18 d0 40 00      02:43:32.363  NOP [Reserved subcommand] [OBS-ACS-
2]
  00 80 38 80 18 d0 40 00      02:43:32.363  NOP [Reserved subcommand] [OBS-ACS-
2]
  00 80 30 00 18 d0 40 00      02:43:32.361  NOP [Reserved subcommand] [OBS-ACS-
2]

Error 367 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 11897 hours (495 days + 17 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown
state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  78 00 01 10 00 00 40

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  00 00 01 10 00 00 40 00      02:43:30.598  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 80 98 00 ff cf 40 00      02:43:26.799  NOP [Reserved subcommand] [OBS-ACS-
2]
  00 80 90 80 fe cf 40 00      02:43:26.798  NOP [Reserved subcommand] [OBS-ACS-
2]
  00 80 90 80 fe cf 40 00      02:43:26.797  NOP [Reserved subcommand] [OBS-ACS-
2]
  00 80 88 00 fe cf 40 00      02:43:26.796  NOP [Reserved subcommand] [OBS-ACS-
2]

Error 366 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 11897 hours (495 days + 17 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown
state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  78 00 01 10 00 00 40

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  00 00 01 10 00 00 40 00      02:43:23.357  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  00 80 40 00 fa cf 40 00      02:43:21.905  NOP [Reserved subcommand] [OBS-ACS-
2]
  00 80 38 80 f9 cf 40 00      02:43:21.904  NOP [Reserved subcommand] [OBS-ACS-
2]
  00 80 38 80 f9 cf 40 00      02:43:21.903  NOP [Reserved subcommand] [OBS-ACS-
2]
  00 80 30 00 f9 cf 40 00      02:43:21.902  NOP [Reserved subcommand] [OBS-ACS-
2]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA
_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     25973         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed: read failure       60%      8088         311
4240

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Interestingly initially there was only 1 short test that showed read failure. Manually running another test showed no failure. I analysed the other drives too but none were peppered with pre-fail this, error that, so somethings off here.

Anyone more versed in this think this information points to disk failure or is there something else? If it is failing, what is the repair process doing and is the array actually functioning like a RAID 10 by properly striping+mirroring once repaired or not?

Comment: Reallocated_Sector_Ct is rather high. Is that continuously increasing?

Comment: Has not increased since I made this post. Will edit if anything changes. Pending sector count has also been 0 throughout.

Answer (score 0):

That intel software is very bad. I can confirm you that from my RAID5 experiences with it. To properly make a check, get HDTune and perform a drive check on each drive. You will also be able to read relevant SMART info directly with it (if you have any warnings, they will be marked with yellow in SMART status). At the SMART status, make sure to check if there are any reallocated sectors. If there are none and no bad sectors, the drives are fine.